# Gephi graph disappears when I click 'Center on Graph'

Tags: gephi

I'm learning to use Gephi. I'm currently looking at a network using the Force Atlas 2 layout. When I click the 'Center on Graph' button on the UI, the network graph disappears from the Workspace screen. I know nothing has happened to the underlying data but the network visualization seems to be just gone. What's happening and how can I get my network graphic back? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this problem as well! All you need to do is stop the format from running, and then click on the 'Center on Graph' button again and it should reappear.

Comment: What do you mean "stop the format from running"?

Comment: I had this problem, and this solution was inadequate. I noticed that when I used the Force Atlas 2 layout (and maybe this happens with others), the graph expands to be really huge. I think the "Center on Graph" button has some zoom limits, which keeps it from zooming far enough out to see anything. I had to run the "Contraction" layout many times to shrink the graph, and then the "Center on Graph" button worked.